# Did the Early Church believe that Mary was sinless?

Tags: early-church, virgin-mary, church-fathers, immaculate-conception

Both Roman Catholic and Orthodox Christians uphold the doctrine of the sinfulness of the blessed Mary, a belief that Mary remained sinless and perfect throughout her entire life, but did any of the Church Fathers (between AD 40-900) believe in the sinlessness of Mary?

Comment: That linked question is asking the reverse, but it also gives a clear answer to your question! Please, you need to search before asking questions!